# How to make flash background same as the computer resolution?

Tags: flash, background-image

I'm now making a program by flash..
i want to ask you why in the program that I make still have white layer in the right and left of the background picture?
if I change it into the resolution of my computer, how if I use another computer with a different resolution?
I hope you can help me.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to resize it and call it everytime you click the fullscreen/normalscreen button.

```
public var backofPage:Image = new Image();
backofPage.source = 'asset/backImage'; //image URL here
```

Let’s name it `cover_back()`. Here is the code:

```
function cover_back() { 
your_image._x=900-Stage.width/2; 
your_image._y=600-Stage.height/2; 
your_image._width=Stage.width; 
your_image._height=Stage.height; 
}
```

Replace 900 and 600 for your original fla width and height. 
Good luck :D

Comment: How to declare the variables of "your_image"? thanks for the help